# A value of type 'DatabaseEvent' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'DataSnapshot' getting this error

Tags: flutter

The below code is giving this error (on the first line) when trying to retrieve data from database.

I am trying to edit contact details that I have saved to my database using the Map.

```
getContactDetail() async {
   DataSnapshot snapshot = await _ref.child(widget.clientKey).once() ;

    Map contact = snapshot.value as Map;

    _nameController.text = contact['name'];

    _numberController.text = contact['number'];

    _emailController.text = contact['email'];

    _addressController.text = contact['address'];

    _shopnameController.text = contact['shopname'];

    _gstController.text = contact['gst'];

    _areaController.text = contact['area'];
    
  }
```

Comment: I am getting this error on first line

Answer (score 0):

`once` now returns a `Future<DatabaseEvent>`

Try:

`DataSnapshot snapshot = (await _ref.child(widget.clientKey).once()).snapshot;`